# Adding Some Feature in JQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-autocomplete, split

This is my Jquery Script Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var months = ['01 - January', '02 - February', '03 - March', '04 - April', '05 - May', '06 - June', '07 - July', '08 - August', '09 - September', '10 - October', '11 - November', '12 - December'];    

$().ready(function() {

    $("#month").autocomplete(months,{minChars: 0,max: 12,autoFill: true,mustMatch: true,matchContains: false,scrollHeight: 220,
    formatItem: function(data, i, total) 
    {
            // don't show the current month in the list of values (for whatever reason)
            if ( data[0] == months[new Date().getMonth()] ) 
                return false;
            return data[0];
    }
    });


    $("#clear").click(function() {
        $(":input").unautocomplete();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">

    <form autocomplete="off">
        <p>
            <label>Single Month:</label>
                <input type="text" id="month" />

        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Now I'm Entering a key '01' It Picks only '01 - January' in tat list . If i select the option by mouse clicking or Typing Enter key, the it will show in the text box. But i need to show only month code in the input filed. In list box only i should show the month code with the month description. I don't want to show the month description in the input box. 
And another one I need to show arrow button to show the list. How can i do this ?

Comment: try to see this its some kind of different code but same concept on what are you trying to do http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMrCx/).   I haven't added all the months.  :)  But the idea is to pass in an array with both pieces of data to the autocomplete widget. The autocomplete widget expects a data source in array format with either:

- Objects containing a label property, a value property, or both
- Simple string values

To add a 'drop down' arrow, see [this sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html) from the jQuery docs.  It is quite lengthy, but looks very good once you are done.